# emgu Matrix<float>.getCols

Tags: c#, matrix, emgucv

I have found a problem when I use the method getCols() of type Matrix.
Check this piece of code:

let suppose that size of orig is [1000, 384] and numFeat is = 50;

```
private Matrix<float> ComputePCA(Matrix<float> orig, int numFeat)
    {
        Matrix<float> avg = new Matrix<float>(1, orig.Cols);
        Matrix<float> eigval = new Matrix<float>(orig.Cols, 1);
        Matrix<float> eigvec = new Matrix<float>(orig.Cols, orig.Cols);
        Matrix<float> featMat = new Matrix<float>(orig.Rows, numFeat);

        CvInvoke.cvCalcPCA(masterMat, avg, eigval, eigvec, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.PCA_TYPE.CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);

        Matrix<float> choosenAutovec = new Matrix<float>(orig.Cols, numFeat);

        choosenAutovec = eigvec.GetCols(0, numFeat - 1);

        featMat = choosenAutovec.Transpose() * orig.Transpose();

        return featMat.Transpose();
    }
```

after eigvec.GetCols I suppose to have a variable choosenAutovec of size [384, 50] right? But I get a matrix [384, 384] instead... Any suggestions to take just the first 50 cols?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first 50 columns is done almost correctly except *numFeat* must not be decremented since the index in the second parameter of **GetCols** is exclusive.

As for matrix size, after calling **GetCols** the *Data* property of *choosenAutovec* references the same array of floats as the similar property of *eigvec*. However, the indexers of *choosenAutovec* will work as if it was a 384 by 50 matrix. You can check it yourself by setting a breakpoint after the *featMat* assignment. *featMat* size will be 50 by 1000 as intended.

At the following page the behavior of **GetCol** (which is similar to **GetCols**) is described in detail in the comment by Canming:
http://www.emgu.com/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19